# Is there a equivalent of C#'s DebuggerStepThrough in Kotlin?

Tags: c#, kotlin, debugging, intellij-idea

I have made an event system in Kotlin where events can be listened to and broadcast, similarly to how events work in C#.

To broadcast an event, I have this line:

```
playerConnected.broadcast(player)
```

Here `playerConnected` is the event and `player` is the context object.

When debugging in IntellIJ, when "stepping into" the broadcast function to see what actions that event listeners do, it instead steps into the `broadcast()` function, which makes sense, and it looks something like this:

```
fun broadcast(args: T) {
    for (listener in listeners) {
        try {
            listener.accept(args)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I am interested in skipping stepping into `broadcast()` and instead step directly into each `accept()` function, where `listener` is a `Consumer<T>`.

In C# I would be able to solve this by adding a `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute` to the `broadcast()` function.

Is there any equivalent attribute in Kotlin or another way to achieve the same in IntellIJ?

Comment: Looking at the Kotlin/IntelliJ documentation, it looks like [you can only direct the debugger to ignore Kotlin's runtime library types and not your own](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-debugger-stepping.html#b59b6d14) (but you _can_ for Java, weird). I suggest you file a feature-request with Jetbrains.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to swallow the exception in `broadcast` rather than passing it upwards?

Comment: Are you targeting the JVM? If so, you can set IntelliJ to ignore the Java counterpart of your Kotlin class which `broadcast` is in.

Comment: @Dai This event system is to run potential usercode (for mods) and if I don't catch the exception, the rest of the listeners will not be executed.

I will however improve the way I do the logging to provide more context for the event l listener developers.

I believe this is similar to how C#'s event system works.

Comment: @Sweeper That's an interesting suggestion, thank you. Can you advice me on how to do that or hint what I can Google to find more information on how to approach that?

Comment: @VapidLinus Do you control the "contract" that the mods have to comply with? If so, you could introduce your own exception types such that mods could throw a `ReallyBadException` which you could re-throw upwards, while still swallowing `NotSoBadException`.

Comment: @Dai I am not sure what you mean, I apologise.

Ideally, the event listeners (mods) would never throw an exception. But modders can be unreliable, write bad code, and accidentally throw a `NullPointerException` or any such.

In those cases, I do not want the other mods to suffer and still have the event broadcast  to them as expected.

Comment: @VapidLinus Ah, you're executing untrusted code - have fun ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting the JVM, and `broadcast` is method of a class, you can set the debugger to ignore that whole class.

Go to IntelliJ IDEA's settings, Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Stepping.

In the "Java" section, you can add a class that you want it to ignore:

[image]

After clicking on the "+" button, you can search for the class in which `broadcast` is in. After you added the class, the whole class will be ignored.

---

If you don't want it to ignore the entire class, here's a "trick" that might work. Rewrite `broadcast` as an extension function *in a separate file*. Let's say your file is called `Foo.kt`. This will actually translate to a Java class called `FooKt`, and it will show up when you search for it in the "list of classes to ignore" dialog box. Of course, not all methods can be rewritten as extension functions, and it doesn't always make sense to rewrite them as extension functions, so this doesn't work all the time :(

Comment: This solves my use case, thank you very much!

The only problem I see is that this is a computer-local solution. Other people who check out this project will have to go through the same process, unless there is a way to syncronize this setting in the project.

In C# this is solved using the attribute, because it will be applied to everyone who checks out the code, not just the single user who set this up.